# Is it possible to set role "account_admin" on Azure Databricks with Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-databricks

I have ADB workspace and i want to create new user with Terraform and set role "Admin" to this workspace user.

I have ADB workspace, user and group.
But I cannot assign user role "Admin" with Terraform:

> resource "databricks_user" "user" {
> provider         = databricks.azure_account
> display_name     = "John Doe"
> user_name        = "john_doe@gmail.com"
> workspace_access = true
> depends_on       = [
> resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.this
> ]
> }
>
> resource "databricks_user_role" "my_user_account_admin" {
> provider         = databricks.azure_account
> user_id          = databricks_user.user.id
> role             = "account_admin"
> }

And I get an error:

> 023-09-06T14:36:50.175+0300 [ERROR] vertex "databricks_user_role.my_user_account_admin" error: cannot read user role: User has no role
> ╷
> Error: cannot read user role: User has no role
> │
> with databricks_user_role.my_user_account_admin,
> on main.tf line 223, in resource "databricks_user_role" "my_user_account_admin":
> 223: resource "databricks_user_role" "my_user_account_admin" {

Comment: Do you have a workspace with Unity Catalog and your users are coming from account level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

```
data "databricks_group" "admins" {
  provider     = databricks.azure_account
  display_name = "admins"
}

resource "databricks_user" "user" { 
  provider = databricks.azure_account
  display_name = "John Doe"
  user_name = "john_doe@gmail.com"
  workspace_access = true 
  depends_on = [ resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.this ]
}

resource "databricks_group_member" "user" {
  provider         = databricks.azure_account
  group_id         = data.databricks_group.admins.id
  member_id        = databricks_user.user.id
  depends_on       = [
    resource.azurerm_databricks_workspace.this
  ]
}
```